# Automatically apply AIP labels based on Metadata

Tags: azure, azure-information-protection

I wish to apply labels to documents in my system using AIP scanner, which will apply the Label to the document after seeing a specific item in the metatdata

i.e. set the metadata to an office file of METADATA_TAG_POLICY, then have a label which has a condition (assuming a custom condition) that checks for existence of the metadata tag and then the sanner will apply the label.
(I assume this would work in the same way as the automatic labelling for the conditions of a credit card number etc. just instead a metadata tag)

Is this possible to be done currently?

Answer (score 0):

AIP scanner can label based in **custom property** only. To enable it use advanced setting named `LabelbyCustomProperty`.

More can be found here for classic client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/client-admin-guide-customizations#migrate-labels-from-secure-islands-and-other-labeling-solutions  and for UL client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/clientv2-admin-guide-customizations